# For loop only gets the first element of a dataframe, and xpath doesn't print the value

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I have the following buggy piece of code which has two problems:
(1) `print(spans)` outputs only the first element of the `df`, and (2) the output of `print(earnings)` is blank. Any help will be appreciated.

```
span_index = {'Number' : [2, 5, 8, 11, 14]}
span_in_df = pd.DataFrame(span_index)
for i, span in enumerate(span_in_df):
        spans = span_in_df.loc[i, 'Number']
        print(spans)
        earnings = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//html/body/main/div[7]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[11]/td[" + str(spans) + "]/span").text
        print(earnings)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the dataframe is necessary in your case, but if it is you need:

```
span_in_df.iterrows()
```

instead of enumerate.

Comment: Thanks, now it's printing every number of `df`` in `print(spans)`, but the output of `print(earnings)` is still blank

Comment: @eumesmo that will depend really on your specific case. Try checking if for e.g the output of find_element_by_path is returning anything for a number (e.g 2). If not, then you have to modify the xpath to properly capture the element.